# Jre installation have no /usr/bin/java file?

Tags: rhel, java

I need to install a specific older version of JRE on a RedHat machine.

So I downloaded `jre-1_5_0_10-linux-i586.rpm` and copied it into `/opt/local`. Then I ran `sh ./jre-1_5_0_10-linux-i586-rpm.bin` and finally I installed it using `rpm -ivh jre-1_5_0_10-linux-i586.rpm`.

Next I copied the jre into my application folder `/usr/java/jre1.5.0_10` `/opt/local/myapp/`. Finally when I tried to set the `alternatives --install` as per this command:

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/local/mpapp/jre1.5.0_10/bin/java 1
```

And I got en error `no such file or directory`?

What could have gone wrong why is the `/usr/bin/java` link is not created?

Comment: Are you sure that path */opt/local/mpapp/jre1.5.0_10/bin/java* exists and the rpm was installed successfully. Please show us the output these commands *ls -l /opt/local/mpapp/jre1.5.0_10/* , *which java*  , *rpm -qa | grep -E "jre|java|jdk"*

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the directory where you saved the file and execute the binary
Change permission to make executable

```
chmod 755 jre-1_5_0_10-linux-i586-rpm.bin
```

Execute RPM, once the file has been executed and type "Yes" to accept the license agreement and allow it to finish the install.

Create a symbolic link like

```
ln -s /usr/java/jre1.5.0.10//bin/java java
```

or

```
ln -s /usr/java/jre1.5.0.10//bin/javac javac
```

Type `java -version` to confirm version and type `rpm -qa | grep jre` to confirm version against rpm database.

Download the file from Java's website with the correct self-extracting file  for either 32 bit or 64 bit depending on your operating system.

Switch the directory to where you want file downloaded

Change permission to executable

Accept the license agreement.

Type `java -version` to confirm version.

Comment: after setting 755 permission which is the correct method to execute the RPM? After creating the symbolic link can I move the jre into myapp folder as per what I am doing currently?